# What's the difference between AcceleratorKey and AccessKey

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I'm writing microsoft UI Automation, there are two attributes AcceleratorKey and AccessKey in AutomationElement class, what's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.acceleratorkeyproperty.aspx):

> Accelerator key combinations invoke an action.

AND

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.accesskeyproperty):

> An access key is a character in the text of a menu, menu item, or label of a control such as a button that activates the attached menu function.

Imagine a typical menubar containing *File* menu. In the file menu there's an *Open file* option. Assigning access key <kbd>F</kbd> to *File* menu would allow pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open this menu. If <kbd>O</kbd> is assigned to *Open file*, pressing <kbd>O</kbd>, when *File* menu is open, would invoke the action assigned to this menu - typically show Open file dialog.

If you assign an <kbd>O</kbd> as an accelarator key to the *Open file* menu, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> anytime (even without the *File* menu open) would invoke it's action - show Open file dialog.

Comment: Or, put another way; accelerators are application keyboard commands you can use in the app without having to go through menus or toolbars: ctrl-O for open, Alt-F4 for close, ctrl-B to toggle bold font, and so on. Accelerator keys are often listed on the right side of a drop-down menu, or appear in a toolbar button tooltip. On the other hand, access keys will set focus to (and sometimes activate, in the case of buttons) UI that is already present on the screen. Access keys are usually underlined.